# Get the source of multiple cell references in Excel Formula

Tags: excel-formula

Let's say I have column and row cells like this:

```
Cell A1:   US Sales       

Cell B1: 100 

Cell A2: CA Sales 

Cell B2: 200

Cell A3: Average Sales  =((A1+A2)/2)
```

This calculates the average sales for two cells.  But I want to show in another cell in text and words how the formula from cell `A3` works.  So in a cell next to `A3`, I would like the end result to show:   `((US Sales + CA Sales)/2)`.

I looked through the forum but haven't seen the exact same question.   I tried using indirect and offset but couldn't really get it.

This is just a sample but I come across this often where I want to see or show other readers in a convenient way how a cell is calculated.  So they don't have to display formula `(Ctrl +`)` and go back and forth tracing the original cells, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`FORMULATEXT`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/Article/FORMULATEXT-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8) function which returns a formula as a string.
In your case put in B3 (for example):

```
=FORMULATEXT(A3)
```

**EDIT**

In Excell 2010 you may use a VBA replace:

```
Function FT(mycell As Range)
    FT = mycell.Formula
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That formula is not even coming up in my Excel.  I have Excel 2010.

Comment: @Skycloud Are you allowed to use VBA?

Comment: Now that only solved part of the puzzle, though.  While this function gives me the formula, which is useful too, but I need to add more to it.  I need get the row and column titles (parts) of the cell that the formula refers to.  For example in the above sample, while this function will get me ((A1+A2)/2), I want to convert that to word form ((US Sales + CA Sales)/2).  In other words, A1 is referring to US Sales and A2 is referring to CA Sales.  In a long spreadsheet, this is helpful in seeing right away how a cell is calculated.

Comment: @Skycloud Have you tried to [name the cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)?

Comment: Hm.. that's a good idea and would be a simpler solution.  I've done that before for my spreadsheets.  But oftentimes when I get sheets from other people, the cells are not named.  So it would be a situation where cells are not named...